# Setting files and directories to match umask setting recursively

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod, umask

Is there a way to go into my home directory and recursively set files and directories to match my umask setting? The issue is, way back when I started using linux, I didn't understand permissions. In order to make stuff work, I set a lot of things to 777 just to keep moving and get stuff done.

Now that I understand a bit more, I've modified my umask setting to give me the permissions I actually need along with setting my primary group the way I need it to be. All is good moving forward, but I still need to deal with a large number of files and directories.

Anyway, I would like to be able to set the files to `rw-rw-r--` and the directories to `rwxrwxr-x` and do that recursively from the home directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example of using the find command with chmod might be useful:

https://superuser.com/questions/91935/how-to-chmod-755-all-directories-but-no-file-recursively

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but it certainly looks like it will do what I need. I'l get back to it later today. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alan's answer above gave me the information I needed to figure this out, but I had to drill down through the comments to find my best solution. The solution I ended up using looked like this:

sudo chmod -R u=rw,g=rw,o=r,a+X /path/to/target

The idea in my case was to have users and groups read and write and others read only. Specifically setting users and groups to rw and others to r effectively removed the 777 permissions I had on pretty much all my files. Then, setting all to X (uppercase X) went back and added execute permission to directories.

Comment: Nice thanks! and I leave this comment for myself `sudo chmod -R a=-x,u=rwX,g=,o= folder` owner rw, others no access, directory with rwx. This will clear existing x on files :)